# Get the number of bytes in a file

Tags: c

Is the following the correct way to get the number of bytes in a file? Are there more straightforward ways, perhaps directly from the `FILE*` object?

```
size_t
num_bytes(FILE *fp)
{
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    return (size_t) ftell(fp);
}
```

Additionally, why does `ftell` return a `long int` and not a `size_t` object? I find it a bit difficult to figure out which "size-ish" functions return `size_t` and which don't. Is there a good way to remember that? Or is the reason that `ftell` isn't `size_t` because it uses `-1L` as the "fail value" ?

Comment: Well, it couldn't return `size_t` because I believe it throws -1 on error. However, I'm not sure why it couldn't use `ssize_t` (Just saw your edit and that you mentioned the possibility too)

Comment: It's signed so that negative values can give an error.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 `ssize_t` is not a Standard C type

Comment: @M.M Ah, ok. That makes sense.

Comment: `size_t` only needs to be large enough to support *in-memory* objects, but files are not in-memory. Think about 32-bit systems where `sizeof(size_t) == 4` but those systems can still have 100GB-sized files on-disk, and `size_t` is too small to represent that. (FAT’s 2GB file size limit does not apply to NTFS, etc)